# Mostrar números negativos de uma matriz python

Tags: python, loop

O desafio é "Crie um programa que mostre os números negativos da matriz"

A matriz é a=[[1, 7, 8, 10],[-3, 6, -9, 11],[5, -4, 2, 0],[12, 3, -8, 9]]

Eu queria saber como colocar os números em uma linha só de resposta pq eu fiz assim:
print('Os números negativos encontrados na matriz a são:')
for i in range(linhas(a)):
for j in range(colunas(a)):
if a[i][j] < 0: #ou seja, negativo:
print(a[i][j])

e dessa forma, está aparecendo de acordo com o loop, alguém pra ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

tudo bem ?

Segue um método bem simples que pode resolver o problema.

```
a=[[1, 7, 8, 10],[-3, 6, -9, 11],[5, -4, 2, 0],[12, 3, -8, 9]]

todos_negativos = []
for dados in a:
    negativos = filter(lambda x : x if x < 0 else 0, dados )
    for x in negativos:
        todos_negativos.append(x)

print(f'Os Numeros Negativos São: {str(todos_negativos)}.'.replace('[', '').replace(']', ''))
```

Utiliando o metodo filter para filtrar os numero negativos da lista e salvando esse numero em um lista vazia, para exibi-la sem precisar iterar sobre ela. convertendo a mesma para um str e usando o replace para tirar os colchetes.
Espero ter Ajudado